# Can't load gems from JRuby jar file within OSGi bundle

Tags: maven, rubygems, osgi, jruby

I'm having trouble loading gems that I've bundled within a jar that's then loaded as an OSGi bundle. I'm a Ruby programmer, so I'm not very familiar with OSGi, Maven, or JRuby.

Our intent is to add the gems to the correct `META-INF/jruby.home` subdirectory and rebuild the `jruby-complete.jar` file, which is then a dependency of this project.

For example, the `cartesian` gem is installed here within `jruby-complete-gems-1.6.8.1.jar` (we're altering the filename to avoid confusion with the pristine JRuby jar):

```
META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cartesian-0.6.7
```

I've verified that the paths exist within the jar. We also have tests running in JUnit that all pass, and I've added some debug output to the Ruby code that's being executed via `ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet()`:

```
DEBUG: Gem.path: ["file:/home/brandanl/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete-gems/1.6.8.1/jruby-complete-gems-1.6.8.1.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/gems/1.8", "/home/brandanl/.gem/jruby/1.9"]
```

So this seems like it's working as designed, until it's loaded into OSGi and I start getting this error:

```
org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- cartesian
  at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:136)
  at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runUnit(ScriptingContainer.java:1263)
  at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1256)
  at com.raritan.polaris.plugins.dynamic.DynamicPluginManager.setPluginLoadPath(DynamicPluginManager.java:123)
  at com.raritan.polaris.plugins.dynamic.Activator.start(Activator.java:54)
```

The Ruby code is essentially just this:

```
require 'cartesian'
```

and my debug output looks like this:

```
DEBUG: Gem.path: ["classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/gems/1.8", "/root/.gem/jruby/1.9"]
```

I've seen several different ways of loading gems, like building jars just containing the gems or installing the gems to the filesystem and changing `jruby.home`, but I want to understand what's wrong with this approach since it works during testing. Our project jar definitely includes the `jruby-complete-gems-1.6.8.1.jar`, and its `MANIFEST.MF` file includes the correct `Bundle-Classpath` directive:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,scripts,lib/jruby-complete-gems-1.6.8.1.jar
```

I've tried loading the gems that are bundled by default with JRuby 1.6.8 — namely `rake` and `sources` — and they fail in the same way, so I think it's a problem with our environment and not with JRuby *per se*.

I'm not sure what else would be helpful to included here, so suggestions are appreciated.